# Is there a particular reason the Moléson funicular is built as a giant bridge?

Tags: bridges, rail, transportation

So I live in Switzerland and there is lots of funiculars in my country. Most of those were built between 1890 and 1930, and for most of those the line is on the ground most of the time, there is bridges only where necessary, just like a regular train line.

The Moléson - Plan-Francey funicular is very particular in that not only it was built much more recently (in the late 1990s), but also the line is basically a huge bridge, the funicular never stands on the ground.

I think this is very weird and should have made the line much more expensive to build for no reason at all. Why is this line built on a giant bridge rather than on the ground with bridges only where necessary? Bridges would have made sense in order to make the line straighter (and thus shorter/faster), but the line is not even straigt anywhere !

- Video of the funicular [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2w-9YD-OS9w).
- Detailed photos and technical explainations about the funicular [here](https://www.remontees-mecaniques.net/bdd/reportage-funi-moleson-village-plan-francey-von-roll-1044.html)

[image: funicular picture from www.remontees-mecaniques.net]

Comment: Do wild or farm animals live along the path of the track? An elevated track would eliminate the possibility of either a cow or deer on the track. My other thought is establishing pillars for the track might be cheaper, easier & quicker than having to do a lot of cut & fill work in the undulating topography.

Comment: How deep does the snow get in winter, and does the train still run?

Comment: I'd agree with Fred, though, in that your assertion that "have made the line much more expensive" needs some backup. Materials/construction technology moved on, to the point where this may have been the cheapest method - especially when you include the cost of time, as well as materials...

Comment: @JonathanRSwift The train runs in winter and serves a small ski resort. (Snow is less and less deep each year due to global warming.)

Comment: ^So, if it were on the ground, it'd be a problem to clear the snow from the tracks? (at least in the late 90's)

Comment: It is a **lot** easier and cheaper to drop footings (below the frost line) every 20 meters or so for the supports than it is to  lay in a track bed with similar depth requirements plus earthmoving to produce a straight-line rise out of hummocky ground.

Comment: @CarlWitthof OK so why are all other funiculars on the ground then?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Not a major problem, as now plow exists on other mountain funiculars, but this is probably part of the answer.

Comment: @Bregalad - Perhaps because the materials/construction technology wasn't available to do it easily/safely at the time? You've noted that the main difference between these railways is that the others are older... It's easier to send an email than a letter, but that doesn't mean that they sent emails 100 years ago

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Precisely, and that's why I suspect the dates of construction plays a role but I have no formal proof - hence the question. The new Stoos funicular, in Schwytz, however is a funicular of moden construction (opened last year) and is on the ground on most of it's way with only a small bridge near the upper station.

Comment: in addition to environmental consideration of wildlife, snow accumulation, and the cost earth work to generate an acceptable profile versus spaced out footing and piers already mentioned, one might considered ease of construction and quality control.  Manufacturing components in a factory setting has much higher quality control for part than field manufactured  components.  Due to the high quality control, you get faster construction which can reduce labour costs.  The price of steel would be another thing to look at.  you would really need to do a cost benefit analysis including life cycle $